# Making an Image move based on data excel

Tags: image, excel

I am curious if it is possible to program an image such as a gas gauge move from empty to fuel based on data that is being imported into an excel spreadsheet. If so does anyone know of any guides to do this and what kind of program will I need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

You'd use VBA and have two images, one of the needle one of the gauge

Then you'd change the angle of the needle based on the data.

Comment: @Brandon Just to make it overly clear... Once you've defined the shape you want to rotate, just call `shape.IncrementRotation` passing a number representing the degrees of rotation, which can be less than a whole number.